# How to insert multi rows from multi dimension array mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My array is like:

```
Array (
    [show_to_mentees] => 1
    [show_profile] => 1
    [job_title] => title
    [mentor_org] => orgnization
    [mentor_gradyear] => 2010
    [mentor_sector] => Array (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 5
    )
    [mentor_interest] => Array (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 4
    )
    [mentor_degree] => 14
    [career_summary] => summary
)
```

I have to insert the bold array values into a MySQL database, and that should be easily searchable.

Either I should insert a new row for each index or create a string of index values and save it in a single row.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? The SQL query, the php required - Can you please clarify.

Comment: i am looking for sql query

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the information in the array is about the 'mentor' itself and the key 'mentor_interest' show the interest of mentor in different sectors.

If above statement is right then, I assume/suggest that you have 'sectors' table in the database.

I would recommend separate tables mentor_sectors and mentor_interests. Also you would need to add each value separately with the mentor_id in another column for linking purpose.

Comment: this array contains registration data of mentor , i am saving this array information in registration table that contains these all fields, mentor_sector and mentor_interests are two columns in which i have to save id of selected options

Comment: Okay, Please check normalization techniques, you need to normalize your data because you have multiple values against a single column. To handle this scenario, I would suggest to create two tables mentor_sector and mentor_interests and add separate row for each value. Also to make it searchable and to make clear relationship you will save mentor_id with the data in these tables. Upvote if you find my answer helpful. Thanks.